# Scraping Youtube video titles with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the title of Youtube video from a specific channel. My current **scraper** is the following:

```
url <- 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmgE6sLiR_cC_0T4fRHpZ0A/videos'
webpage <- read_html(url)
titles_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '#contents')
titles <- html_text(titles_html)
```

I'm pretty sure the node is not the correct one, but I can't seem to find anything through Google Chrome SelectorGadget.

Anyone knows how to get data in this case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I highly recommend using the package tuber and getting access through google API.

Answer (score 0):

`#contents` is correct but need more processing, use `h3 a` to get title of every video.